# What is the uniform type identifiers for Ada/Fortran source files?

Tags: macos, fortran, ada, uti

Does anyone know the Uniform Type Identifiers (UTIs) for Ada/Fortran source files? I can't find anything about it on the Internet.

Comment: Yes, OS X. As a ISO language, t is hard to believe it does not have UTI and SQL has UTI as org.iso.sql.

Comment: Sorry, that was my misunderstanding of what UTI is, disregard.